# Imageview Background transparent

Tags: android

I set an image view on activity, but how can I remove the white space around the image view while image is .GIF?
      '  '

Comment: Use a PNG image with transparent background

Comment: set background of imageview to android:background="@android:color/transparent"

Comment: also used bt not work

Comment: <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/regs"
       />

Comment: can you post screen shot

Comment: yeah......this code work.thank u

Answer (score 0):

you need to have a background to the `Button` element, you can try and create a `selector` drawable and set it to the background of the button (assuming you want pres states)

for more, try reading [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use imageview for png image. Use view or linerlayout.